# Can't use state.data.parameters in render when setstate({data: this.props.somefunction()}) componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

Please HELP!

I fill data in componentdidupdate

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(isEmpty(this.props.tofiConstants)) return;

  const { doUsers, dpUsers } = this.props.tofiConstants;
  if (prevProps.cubeUsers !== this.props.cubeUsers) {
    this.setState({
      data: somefunc(doing here something)       
    });
  }

  console.log(this.state.data);
}
```

and then  i want use the state in render

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="profileScreen">{this.state.fullname}</div>
  );
}
```

constructor is here

```
constructor(props) {
  super (props);

  this.state = {
    data: []
  };
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You are setting the `data` slice of your state, however you are accessing the `fullname` slice of it in your `render` function. Probably what you wanted to do is `const { data: { fullname } } = this.state;` and then access it directly using `fullname` in your `return` statement.

Comment: I can't see where you define fullname in your state. Im confused